# Visual Studio 2013 random crashing

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Random crashes have started since yesterday in VS2013 when I'm just navigating in the IDE, or editing a file, or debugging, or just plain doing nothing.

Its an MVC 5 project but has happened to another solution also. I'm on latest updates for VS2013, but don't think I've upgraded any major nuget packages recently.  Have Atlassian plug-in for JIRA, web essentials but no updates to these recently either.

I can probably move these solutions now to VS2015, which doesn't seem to give me the issue, so I can workaround it.  Just need to get the rest of the company upgraded.

Only logs I can find are in EventViewer, showing 2 entries per crash.

Any other logs that can help pinpoint what's failing?

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssServiceResponseException
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.HandleResponse(System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase+<SendAsync>d__a.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase+<SendAsync>d__2`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient+<GetConnectionDataAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.VssServerDataProvider+<ConnectAsync>d__5.MoveNext()

Exception Info: System.AggregateException
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.VssServerDataProvider.CheckForServerUpdates()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.VssServerDataProvider.FindServiceDefinition(System.String, System.Guid, System.Guid)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.VssServerDataProvider.LocationForCurrentConnection(System.String, System.Guid, System.Guid)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.VssServerDataProvider.<GetRemoteDataProvider>b__d(System.Guid)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[[System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].GetOrAdd(System.Guid, System.Func`2<System.Guid,System.__Canon>)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.VssServerDataProvider.GetRemoteDataProvider(System.Guid)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.VssServerDataProvider.LocationForCurrentConnection(System.String, System.Guid, System.Guid)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.VssConnection.GetClientInstance(System.Type, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpRequestSettings, System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler[])
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.VssConnection.GetClientInstance(System.Type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.VssConnection.GetClientServiceImpl(System.Type, System.Func`2<System.Type,System.Object>)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.VssConnection.GetClientServiceImpl[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Func`2<System.Type,System.Object>)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.VssConnection.GetClient[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.VssConnectionWrapper.GetClient[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession+<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.IOnlineLicensingSupport.GetEncodedClientRightsAsync>d__25.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.VsOnlineLicensing+<RefreshClientRightsImplAsync>d__e.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.VsOnlineLicensing+<RefreshClientRightsOrPiggybackAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.VsOnlineLicensing+<PollForClientRights>d__16.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Poller+<PollAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_1(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

and this one;

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 12.0.40629.0, time stamp: 0x5590c8a4
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.19110, time stamp: 0x56842600
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000c42d
Faulting process id: 0x1e30
Faulting application start time: 0x01d15f427bb58f14
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 246fd811-cb37-11e5-af51-bc305bdf85ce
```

Comment: Have you installed new anti-virus software or any new hardware drivers?

Comment: No.  Windows 7 machine, configured to prompt for confirmation before installing any updates.  None applied recently.  ESET anti-virus running - no choice on that, no updates here as far as I know except the databases.

Comment: so no changes in software on the system at all since before it started happening?